# Beyond compare remote with local file

Tags: ssh, diff, beyondcompare

I want to compare two text files one on remote the other local. With diff I would do that with

```
ssh user@login "cat myfile.txt" | diff - local.txt
```

Is there a way to perform the same comparison using Beyond Compare? If I do

```
ssh user@login "cat myfile.txt" | bcompare - local.txt
```

I get only the local file displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One neat trick that I use in such cases is to use `sshfs` to make the remote directory appear as a local one to beyond compare:

```
sshfs user@host:/opt/data /tmp/transfer
```

Then you can use any diffing tool to compare your local data with the remote one via `diff -Nur /local/data/dir /tmp/transfer` or with beyond compare as usual and you can copy files back and forth as needed.

Note, you might need to install sshfs via your package manager, e.g. on Debian/Ubuntu via `apt-get install sshfs`

Possible options:

- `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no`: If you need password authentication, but ssh first tries too many private key authenticaitions, not needed if you use private key auth for this server or no private key auth at all
- `-o sshfs_debug`: Print out more information if authentication/connection fails
- `-o idmap=user`: Use the idmap=user option to translate the UID of the connecting user to the remote user
- `-o gid=1000`: uid, gid - set reported ownership of files to given values; uid is the numeric user ID of your user, gid is the numeric group ID of your user.
- `-o nomap=error`: Fail if user mapping cannot be done

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS for more details.

Comment: Wow, your trick works great. Would you mind just explain what the options stand for. Thanks

Comment: Done, I just happened to use these in one scenario, they are not mandatory, but often are useful, I explained a bit what they do and provided a link to some more information.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond Compare Pro includes built-in SFTP support, so you can pass an SFTP URL directly to it as a command-line argument.

```
bcompare local.txt sftp://user:password@server/folder/file.txt
```

If you don't provide a password in the URL, Beyond Compare will prompt you for a password.

```
bcompare local.txt sftp://user@server/folder/file.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is my case. I would like to compare a local file with a file I have on a cluster remote directory. I usually access it doing
`ssh name@login.xxx "cd my/directory/" `

Comment: Many servers that support SSH also support SFTP. In your example, you'd use the command line: `bcompare sftp://name@login.xxx/my/directory/file.ext`

Comment: @ChrisKennedy, does Beyond Compare Pro  support SFT with private RSA key authentification (analog to `-i` option of `ssh`)? Or only password-based authentification?

Comment: Yes, Beyond Compare Pro supports private key authentication for SFTP. https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_sftp_privatekey

Comment: Nice, but this does not seem to work with AWS CodeCommit, which *only* accepts urls starting with `ssh://`, not the default `sftp://` used by BC. Is there any workaround for specifying a different protocol in the url? e.g. `ssh://` or `https://`

Comment: Sorry, Beyond Compare doesn't support ssh:// URLs.

Answer (score 0):

BeyondCompare offers comparing files on local files system and remote. For accessing remote files e.g. on linux server, try Browse using profile which gives option of QuickConnect. Select FTP profile --> select protocol sftp (ssh2). Provide your host, port, user and password.  Click save and connect. I t will show the remote file system to choose any remote file or folder.